Finding a similar matrix with a zero block to a given matrix
I have an $n\times n$ matrix $A$. I have $r$ eigenvalues of $A$ and their corresponding eigenvectors.
I would like to construct a matrix $B$ similar to $A$ of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 
     S_{r\times r} & \star\\\ 0 & \star 
\end{bmatrix}$ (where the $r$ eigenvalues that I have, will be the eigenvalues of $S_{r\times r}$.
($\textbf{Restriction}$: I am not allowed to find the remaining $(n-r)$ eigenvalues of $A$.)
I have been able myself to find a matrix $B$ of this form which is $\textbf{orthogonally}$ similar to my $A$. But for some reason that orthogonality is too restrictive for my purpose.
I will very greatly appreciate your insight or any reference that you can direct me to.
Thanks a lot in advance,

I think you should explain why (i) you are "not allowed " to find the other eigenvalues (ii) why being orthogonally similar won't do (why can't you pretend you didn't notice the orthogonality).

Thanks a lot for your reply. I need the matrix of "transfer" to be of a certain block form. Unfortunately, the moment that matrix is orthogonal, that form becomes impossible.

I think you need to specify all that in the question. As it stands it's trivial (if $r<n$) to provide a non-orthogonal basis wrt $A$ has your prescribed form. But I don't know whether it does what you really seem to need. And when you revise your question, make explicit whether this is a real matrix, whether the $r$ ev are distinct, whether they are real ...

Thanks a lot for your reply.  The matrix is real and the eigenvalues can be repeated.
i) My objective is to find all eigenvalues of A (reductively) through this process.
ii) This was a very natural thing to ask. I need the matrix of "transfer" to be of a certain form. Unfortunately, the moment that matrix is orthogonal, that form becomes impossible.

Your question needs to be edited to include all these facts. Now that you say that the eigen values can be repeated I am not clear what you mean when you say you know their corresponding eigenvectors: are you interested when you have, let's say $r=27$, all eigenvalues (to date) equal to $0$ but with only one l.i. eigenvector?
